# How authenticate user in Jboss with LDAP using userName, not CN

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, ldap, login-config.xml

I'm trying to authenticate users against LDAP for an application deployed in Jboss. Users authenticate fine, but for the user field, I have to enter the full name, with the username it does not work.

I wonder if the problem is the LDAP configuration or if I'm leaving any configuration parameter in the login-config.xml

This is the code of the login-config.xml:

```
       <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule" flag="required">

            <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</module-option>
            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url">ldap://ldap-server-ip:389/</module-option>
            <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication">simple</module-option>

            <module-option name="principalDNPrefix">CN=</module-option>
            <module-option name="principalDNSuffix">,OU=DEPT. PROGRAMARI,OU=LIMIT - CECOMASA,DC=LIMIT_CECOMASA,DC=LOCAL</module-option>

            <module-option name="baseCtxDN">ou=LIMIT - CECOMASA,dc=LIMIT_CECOMASA,dc=LOCAL</module-option>
            <module-option name="baseFilter">(sAMAccountName={0})</module-option>
            <module-option name="uidAttributeID">member</module-option>
            <module-option name="matchOnUserDN">true</module-option>

            <module-option name="rolesCtxDN">ou=LIMIT - CECOMASA,dc=LIMIT_CECOMASA,dc=LOCAL</module-option>
            <module-option name="roleFilter">(member={0})</module-option>               
            <module-option name="roleAttributeID">cn</module-option>
            <!-- module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN">true</module-option -->

            <module-option name="searchTimeLimit">10000</module-option>
            <module-option name="searchScope">SUBTREE_SCOPE</module-option>                      

        </login-module>
```

and this is the LDIF info of my user on the LDAP server:

```
dn: CN=Andreu Serra,OU=DEPT. PROGRAMARI,OU=LIMIT - CECOMASA,DC=LIMIT_CECOMASA,DC=LOCAL
objectClass: user
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: Andreu Serra
instanceType: 4
objectCategory: CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=LIMIT_CECOMASA,DC=LO
 CAL
accountExpires: 9223372036854775807
badPasswordTime: 130576882951482672
badPwdCount: 0
codePage: 0
countryCode: 0
displayName: Andreu Serra
distinguishedName: CN=Andreu Serra,OU=DEPT. PROGRAMARI,OU=LIMIT - CECOMASA,D
 C=LIMIT_CECOMASA,DC=LOCAL
givenName: Andreu
homeMDB:: Q049QWxtYWPDqW4gZGVsIGJ1esOzbiAoU0VSVkVSMDApLENOPVByaW1lciBncnVwby
 BkZSBhbG1hY2VuYW1pZW50byxDTj1JbmZvcm1hdGlvblN0b3JlLENOPVNFUlZFUjAwLENOPVNlc
 nZlcnMsQ049UHJpbWVyIGdydXBvIGFkbWluaXN0cmF0aXZvLENOPUFkbWluaXN0cmF0aXZlIEdy
 b3VwcyxDTj1MSU1JVCAtIENFQ09NQVNBLENOPU1pY3Jvc29mdCBFeGNoYW5nZSxDTj1TZXJ2aWN
 lcyxDTj1Db25maWd1cmF0aW9uLERDPUxJTUlUX0NFQ09NQVNBLERDPUxPQ0FM
homeMTA: CN=Microsoft MTA,CN=SERVER00,CN=Servers,CN=Primer grupo administrat
 ivo,CN=Administrative Groups,CN=LIMIT - CECOMASA,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=S
 ervices,CN=Configuration,DC=LIMIT_CECOMASA,DC=LOCAL
lastLogoff: 0
lastLogon: 130578294930208368
legacyExchangeDN: /o=LIMIT - CECOMASA/ou=Primer grupo administrativo/cn=Reci
 pients/cn=andreus
logonCount: 481
mail: andreus@limit.es
mailNickname: andreus
mDBUseDefaults: TRUE
memberOf: CN=RSC_ADMIN,OU=DEPT. PROGRAMARI,OU=LIMIT - CECOMASA,DC=LIMIT_CECO
 MASA,DC=LOCAL
memberOf: CN=TerminalServer,OU=LIMIT - CECOMASA,DC=LIMIT_CECOMASA,DC=LOCAL
memberOf: CN=Dept. Programari,OU=DEPT. PROGRAMARI,OU=LIMIT - CECOMASA,DC=LIM
 IT_CECOMASA,DC=LOCAL
msExchALObjectVersion: 57
msExchHomeServerName: /o=LIMIT - CECOMASA/ou=Primer grupo administrativo/cn=
 Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=SERVER00
msExchMailboxGuid:: Xff5XoFGiUyq6szgBxtZbw==
msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor:: AQAE77+9eAAAAO+/vQAAAAAAAAAUAAAABABkAAEAAA
 AAAhQAAwACAAEBAAAAAAAFCgAAAEkATQBJAFQAXwBDAEUAQwBPAE0AQQBTAEEALwBjAG4APQBDA
 G8AbgBmAGkAZwB1AHIAYQB0AGkAbwBuAC8AYwBuAD0AAADvv70BAQUAAAAAAAUVAAAA77+9Cu+/
 vRF877+9JA1DFwoy77+9AQAAAQUAAAAAAAUVAAAA77+9Cu+/vRF877+9JA1DFwoy77+9AQAA
msExchPoliciesIncluded: {C2EA965C-E5EE-4990-9447-1B5A7745E80C},{26491CFC-9E5
 0-4857-861B-0CB8DF22B5D7}
msExchUserAccountControl: 0
name: Andreu Serra
objectGUID:: R0ByiBmTN0WR4x/c6bruEw==
objectSid:: AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAuwraEXzrJA1DFwoyqgcAAA==
primaryGroupID: 513
proxyAddresses: smtp:andreus@LIMIT_CECOMASA.LOCAL
proxyAddresses: X400:c=us;a= ;p=LIMIT - CECOMASA;o=Exchange;s=Serra;g=Andreu
 ;
proxyAddresses: SMTP:andreus@limit.es
pwdLastSet: 130410870859571872
sAMAccountName: andreus
sAMAccountType: 805306368
showInAddressBook: CN=Lista global de direcciones predeterminada,CN=All Glob
 al Address Lists,CN=Address Lists Container,CN=LIMIT - CECOMASA,CN=Microsof
 t Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=LIMIT_CECOMASA,DC=LOCAL
showInAddressBook: CN=Todos los usuarios,CN=All Address Lists,CN=Address Lis
 ts Container,CN=LIMIT - CECOMASA,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Confi
 guration,DC=LIMIT_CECOMASA,DC=LOCAL
sn: Serra
textEncodedORAddress: c=us;a= ;p=LIMIT - CECOMASA;o=Exchange;s=Serra;g=Andre
 u;
userAccountControl: 66048
userPrincipalName: andreus@LIMIT_CECOMASA.LOCAL
uSNChanged: 5052147
uSNCreated: 5052138
whenChanged: 20140404121211.0Z
whenCreated: 20140404121125.0Z
```

The only problem is that I have type Andres Serra / password in the authentication popup and not andreus / password as would be expected. I've tried a thousand combinations for the login-module, I hope 1001 will be the good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened was that the LDAP was misconfigured. Normally the LDAP user identifier (uid) is used to form the DN (Distinguished Name), but in our LDAP short name is used. Fortunately, in the LDAP client that worked as supposed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <module-option name="matchOnUserDN">false</module-option>
 <module-option name="uidAttributeID">sAMAccountName</module-option>
```

-jim

Comment: Thanks jim, but That doesn´t works neither. I`ve tried by changing the two attributes you've told me, further, also commenting the preffix and suffix because I dont want to contrast the entered username with the Dinstinguished Name, because in that case, I have no choice but to put the full name , since in our LDAP, unlike most examples I've seen online, the DN is formed with the CN attribute and not the uid.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that we can not connect as we want (and as usual) with the configuration we have. At least not with the implementation of org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule. Maybe with LdapExtLoginModule that could, but I read somewhere that is only available from version 4 of Jboss, and we are using 3.2 

Any more ideas?

Comment: It stems from LdapLoginModule javadoc (and also from its code) that "matchOnUserDN" parameter is used for user roles matching. So it has no influence on authentication: "matchOnUserDN : A flag indicating if the search for user roles should match on the user's fully distinguished name. If false just the username is used as the match value. If true, the userDN is used as the match value."